# how to trace the data whether the destination stop using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am newbie in programming.. I have table test and 3 columns(source, from and destination) below..

**Table test**

```
  source     from                destination     
  01         VALID/NUM-6283      Local/00000042;1
  02         Local/00000042;2    Local/00000043;1
  03         Local/00000043;2
  04         NOT_VALID/NUM-0000  Local/00000000;0
  05         Local/000000d2;2
  06         Local/0000002b;2    Local/000000d2;1    
  07         VALID/NUM-1234      Local/0000002b;1
```

working [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac94f/1)

the first row (source 01) has :

```
  from                destination  
  VALID/NUM-6283      Local/00000042;1
```

the 2nd row (source 02) has :

```
  from                destination  
  Local/00000042;2    Local/00000043;1
```

the 3rd row (source 03) has :

```
  from                destination  
  Local/00000043;2
```

the destination on 3rd row is empty..as you can see the the first row. the column "destination" has Local/00000042;1;

then the second row; on the column "from" has Local/00000042;2;

there last character is "42;1" and "42;2";

then it continues til "43;1" in "source02->destination" and 43;2 in "source03->from"

is there any way to do that using mysql...

i want to focus on the data on column "from" that has only a prefix VALID! e.g. (VALID/NUM-6283)

then trace where on column "destination" where it ends ...

```
  VALID/NUM-6283   ->  VALID/NUM-6283  ->  Local/00000042;1  -> 
  Local/00000042;2  ->  Local/00000043;1  ->  Local/00000043;2  -> 
  ends on "destination" in "source03"
```

hope its make sense.... can anyone tell me how to do it optimizely?? because what if the table consist of a thousands of data....

Comment: your question barely makes any sense. but from what understand you need to take `VALID` out of `from` column and create new column for it.  You have multiple data within the same column (redundancy) which is a wrong table design. Other thing is your column naming. Do not use reserved words (`FROM`) as a column name. Please try to make your question more clear.

Comment: sorry for the column name "from" sir.... But for that redundancy issue.... there is a valid reason why it should like that..... please help me with my topic sir

Comment: No need to be sorry :) . what is the reason for the redundancy? You need a query or? If you don't make ur question more clear we won't b able to help you.

Comment: i want to query the column "from" where it started and in the column "destination" where it was end

Comment: VALID/NUM-6283   ->  VALID/NUM-6283  ->  Local/00000042;1  -> 
          Local/00000042;2  ->  Local/00000043;1  ->  Local/00000043;2  -> 
          ends on "destination" in "source03"

Comment: @Masoud - sir??

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you are looking for a way to traverse your table as a tree and trace an item to see where it ended. I don't like your table desing and also what you are doing but I have a possible solution for it.

I cannot think of a simple query to do it but programmatically its possible. I have written a procedure to handle it. Please note that this procedure assumes that final destination is inserted into the table after start point and also this might not work in all your cases since I do not now what are the other possible input patterns. Try this. Hope it helps

```
drop procedure if exists traceMe;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE traceMe(in input varchar(80))
BEGIN
  DECLARE bDone INT;
  DECLARE src,frm,des,startPoin varchar(80);    -- or approriate type

  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT * FROM table_test;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

  OPEN curs;
SELECT Destination into startPoin from table_test where `from` = input;
  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO src,frm,des;
     -- select CONCAT(LEFT(startPoin,LENGTH(startPoin) -1),'2');
     -- select frm;
    IF (frm = CONCAT(LEFT(startPoin,LENGTH(startPoin) -1),'2')) Then
      Set startPoin = des;
    END IF;
  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
  SELECT startPoin;
END$$

delimiter ;

call traceMe('VALID/NUM-6283');
```

Comment: wooow.... sir... is it possible to do it in left join or not???

Comment: this is a stored procedure. Please Google it up.